# Has anybody measured the Schwarzschild radius of a black hole and does the radius equal the radius predicted from the mass?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, astrophysics, astronomy, quasars

Have schwarzschild radii been measured from quasars or lensing black holes of known mass?

Comment: Note that astrophysical black holes, which rotate, are described by the Kerr metric instead of the Schwarzchild metric. A search term is “event horizon telescope.”

Comment: Yes I see from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Horizon_Telescope  that the mass and diameter of M87 have been measured and agree with theory as far as experimental accuracy allows.

Comment: Note that the EHT does not actually resolve the event horizon (despite its name).